# What if you make fun of a mentally ill person?

Tags: tawba

I have a cousin who is mentally ill. I often made fun of her. I didn’t do it directly infront of her but infront of other people and with my mom. Now i am extremely ashamed of it. I am afraid her parents knows about my doings. Our families don’t have good relationship so i couldn't say sorry to them. But i am regretful. What if her family gives me curse? How can i ask forgiveness?

Comment: "I didn’t do it directly infront of her but infront of other people and with my mom. " this actually is Gheebah which is among the worst sins and making fun of a person that Allah has made like this is really a serious matter you should repent of sincerely.

Comment: How can I ask forgiveness?

Comment: You may take a look at [Does the process of repentance differ significantly based on the sin?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/41427/does-the-process-of-repentance-differ-significantly-based-on-the-sin)

Answer (score 0):

What you did was wrong and was extremely disrespectful. But, you seem to be repenting and regretting over your actions. Remember make dua and Allah always forgives.