# Is this haram what I did? Please answer I’m really scared

Tags: halal-haram, sin, tawba

Once in school my Muslim friend got in trouble for doing something to another kid. Then a few days after he had a conversation with that kid and he tells me that the kid called him something very bad. But I was nowhere near them when this was happening and this is all what he told me what happened even though he could have been lying. Then he tells me that if any teacher asks me about that conversation then I have to tell the teacher that the kids called him a bad word. So the next day the teacher asks me what if i heard anything between then, and I said what my friend told me to say. Does this count as false witness? Keep in mind that I’m that I’m baligh and my sins are being recorded. The only reason I told the teacher what my friend wanted me to say was to get him out of trouble and because he is a very good friend of mine. So please, is this haram and what can I do to erase that sin? Keep in mind that I did the most sincere tobah i ever did a few months after that so does that mean the sin is cleaned and wiped off my book? And also, let’s  say Allah erase that sin, will he still ask about it on the of judgement?

Comment: There's a very complete answer here.https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/41427/does-the-process-of-repentance-differ-significantly-based-on-the-sin In brief, as you did this as a child you can repent and need not fear punishment.

Answer (score 0):

salaam,
Remember that Allah (swt) is the most forgiving, most merciful, and yes since you did not witness it, it may have been best not to comment. However, we are all humans and we all make mistakes daily. Do not beat yourself up. The fact that you feel guilty and are repenting shows that you are firm in your faith and are trying to do good. Remember that Allah (swt) is kind and only asks you to repent and learn from your mistake, which it looks like you have. Don't worry, learn and move on because no one is perfect. :) Hope that helps!
-MuslimGap