# Laughing at friend crying, pride in my heart

Tags: forgiveness

---

we got our results back for a test. i got a good result Alhamdullilah but this other girl did not and she started crying. I started laughing at her crying, not so much out of spite of her bad grade, but her crying just made me laugh. I know it was wrong, i should have controlled myself. Also, please bear in mind this was not really normal of me to laugh at someone crying.
Now i am scared i had some pride in my heart, because i got better than her. I also might have been thinking that because of all my recent good grades, in somehow immune of getting bad. I forgot Allah is the one giving her the bad grade and giving me the good grade, and in a split second the roles would be reversed and i would be getting bad grades. I am ashamed of thinking this way, especially as i did not even thinking i did particularly well in my test, i just prayed a lot. Allah saved me as well because lots and lots of people who get so much better than me got bad and i still did good. I am quite guilty of laughing at her, how can i best ask for Allah’s forgiveness. I am scared that in the moment i was laughing he got angry at me and made me get bad in my other subjects which i have not yet received grades of.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does the process of repentance differ significantly based on the sin?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/41427/does-the-process-of-repentance-differ-significantly-based-on-the-sin)

Comment: this is true thanks a lot.