# what is the punishment for killing kittens and how can a friend of mine redeem himself

Tags: pets

My friend who was 13 years old at that time killed 4 kittens and hurt alot of other cats[kicking them ,etc] . I was just wondering what would be the punishment for him and how can he redeem himself . I have asked other friends as well but they have no answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does the process of repentance differ significantly based on the sin?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/41427/does-the-process-of-repentance-differ-significantly-based-on-the-sin)

Comment: There isn't any specific punishment. Its a sin like many others and can be either forgiven or punished by a ta'zeer punishment in this world (which depends on the judgement of the person's parent or guardian or a judge) and can be either forgiven or punished in the hereafter depending on the will of Allah. The way to redeem himself is to repent, whose process is covered in the linked duplicate above.

Answer (score 0):

All needed is Tawbah. Allah forgives all kinds of sins, as stated in this verse:

> قُلۡ يَٰعِبَادِيَ ٱلَّذِينَ أَسۡرَفُواْ عَلَىٰٓ أَنفُسِهِمۡ لَا
> تَقۡنَطُواْ مِن رَّحۡمَةِ ٱللَّهِۚ إِنَّ ٱللَّهَ يَغۡفِرُ ٱلذُّنُوبَ
> جَمِيعًاۚ إِنَّهُۥ هُوَ ٱلۡغَفُورُ ٱلرَّحِيمُ 53
>
> (VI) SAY: "My servants who have acted extravagantly against themselves
> still do not despair of God's mercy. God forgives all sins; He is
> the Forgiving, the Merciful. [(53)](https://quran.inoor.ir/en/ayah/39/53/)

It is needed to do Tawbah and leave the sin. and if the sin has been related to rights of other people, The lost right must be compensated. but about animals you can do some helps to animals to ensure it is compensated. but only tawbah is enough when there is no lost right of other people.

> يَـٰٓأَيُّهَا ٱلَّذِينَ ءَامَنُواْ تُوبُوٓاْ إِلَى ٱللَّهِ تَوۡبَةٗ
> نَّصُوحًا عَسَىٰ رَبُّكُمۡ أَن يُكَفِّرَ عَنكُمۡ سَيِّـَٔاتِكُمۡ
> وَيُدۡخِلَكُمۡ جَنَّـٰتٖ تَجۡرِي مِن تَحۡتِهَا ٱلۡأَنۡهَٰرُ يَوۡمَ لَا
> يُخۡزِي ٱللَّهُ ٱلنَّبِيَّ وَٱلَّذِينَ ءَامَنُواْ مَعَهُۥۖ نُورُهُمۡ
> يَسۡعَىٰ بَيۡنَ أَيۡدِيهِمۡ وَبِأَيۡمَٰنِهِمۡ يَقُولُونَ رَبَّنَآ
> أَتۡمِمۡ لَنَا نُورَنَا وَٱغۡفِرۡ لَنَآۖ إِنَّكَ عَلَىٰ كُلِّ شَيۡءٖ
> قَدِيرٞ 8
>
> (II) You who believe, turn to God in frank repentance. Perhaps your
> Lord will remit your evil deeds for you and show you into gardens
> through which rivers flow, on a day when God will not let the Prophet
> be humiliated. Those who believe will stand alongside him, their light
> streaming on ahead of them and to their right. They will say: " Our
> Lord, perfect our light for us, and forgive us! You are Capable of
> everything!" [(8)](https://quran.inoor.ir/en/ayah/66/8/)