# I drank alcohol February 16 and Ramadan is in march 11. I didn’t know about the 40 day rule but astagfurallah I drank. How can I repent to Allah

Tags: halal-haram

Please help me. I made a big mistake and I need your help. I want to know if I can repent to Allah S.W.T and inshallah make my prayers and fast be accepted.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does the process of repentance differ significantly based on the sin?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/41427/does-the-process-of-repentance-differ-significantly-based-on-the-sin)

Answer (score 0):

**Genuine** repentance suffices.

For your repentance to be really genuine, read:
https://islamqa.info/en/answers/289765/conditions-of-repentance